# Dynamically enable grouping in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to enable/disable grouping dynamically on a jqGrid on a button click, but it does not seem to be working. I am trying with this code but no luck

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
     $('#mygrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { grouping:true });
});
```

The grouping is generated with the following

```
groupingView : { 
    groupField : ['product'], 
    groupColumnShow : [true], 
    groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>']
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the 'groupingToggle' and 'groupingRemove' methods found here -- http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouping feature has [some method](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agrouping#methods) which you could use: `groupingRemove`, `groupingGroupBy`, `groupingToggle`.

To remove the grouping you can use

```
grid.jqGrid('groupingRemove', true);
```

(where `var grid = $('#list');`). To enable grouping you can use the code like

```
grid.jqGrid('groupingGroupBy',['product']);
```

or for example

```
grid.jqGrid(
    'groupingGroupBy',
    ['product'],
    { groupText: ['<b>Product(s): "{0}" - {1} item(s)</b>'] }
);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again Oleg - I think this is nearly the 20th jQGrid problem/issue that you have helped me solve!

Comment: @FastTrack: You are welcome! By the way, it's very important to have options corresponds to [the grouping limitations](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping#limitations). For example if you forget to include `gridview: true` option then the method `groupingGroupBy` will not work. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13194985/315935) for details.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I have `gridview: true` in my grids ever since I read a few of your answers that said it greatly improves performance.